# Focusing a text input using a ref works but focusing a radio input does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a simple React example created here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-browser-bjj9z8?file=/src/App.js

The goal is to have 2 outcomes:

1. The first button causes the text input to gain focus (this works)
2. The second button causes the radio input to gain focus (this does not work)

I have implemented the refs and focus events on the buttons in the same way but the radio input does not gain focus for some reason. Attempting to tab and shift+tab through the document will show that both input elements have the ability to be focused.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to use .click() instead .focus(), something like this

```
<button tabIndex="-1" onClick={() => radioInputRef.current.click()}>
  Focus radio input
</button>
```